# How to save Python dict as NodeJS dict?

Tags: python, node.js, json, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
my_dict = {"A":"a", "B":"b", "C":"c"}
```

which, if I save it using `json` as follows:

```
with open('my_dict.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(my_dict , fp, indent=4)
```

would look as this:

```
{
    "A": "a",
    "B": "b",
    "C": "c"
}
```

However, I am wondering if there is a way to save the Python dictionary as a NodeJS dictionary, so it will look like this:

```
{
    A: "a",
    B: "b",
    C: "c"
}
```

Comment: Then it's not valid JSON anymore… Maybe you're looking for YAML instead?

Comment: without the double quotes It will be act as variable in the python program. so you need to put the keys inside the double quotes

Comment: @Vidya It won't "act as variable" _in JSON_, which is what the question is about…

Comment: @deceze I actually needed exactly the way I wrote it in my question. YAML won't separate the different elements with comma nor write brackets.

Comment: What you want is *not JSON.* What do you need it for? Why does it *have to* look exactly like that?

Comment: Well, it will work just fine *with* the quotes in Javascript/node. Why insist on having it without quotes?

Comment: I didn't know you can use it with quotes too. I am very new to NodeJS. Thanks!

Comment: JSON is a valid *subset* of Javascript. In other words, any JSON is entirely valid Javascript. It's just a more *strict subset*, e.g. keys must have quotes in JSON while you have the option between quotes or no quotes in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the quotation it won't be a valid `json` file. But if you really need to just have this format in a file you can save it in `.txt` file and then load it as a string:

```
with open('my_dict.txt', 'w') as fp:
    regex = re.compile("\"(.*?)\":")
    st = regex.sub(r'\1:', json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4))
    fp.write(st)
```

so you would have a `txt` with the desired format.

```
{
    A: "a",
    B: "b",
    C: "c"
}
```